# java.util.InputMismatchException error

Tags: java

Hey everyone I'am working on a project and am having a little trouble I am receiving a java.util.InputMismatchException   any help would be greatly appreciated. I am really new to programming in java so forgive me if I've made a obvious dumb mistake.  The object of the program is to read a file acquire the first three lines to use for 6 different variables(three integers and three strings) then read the rest of the file, format it,and do some math then put it into a new file.  The file I am taking data from is formatted as follows.

> Court 50
>
> Box 10
>
> Club 25
>
> Rascal Conway 10 Box
>
> Loretta Barrett 3 Court
>
> Loras Tyrell 5 Club
>
> Margaery Tyrell 8 Box.

Here is the code:

```
public class ProjectTicket {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /////////////////////// amount of tickets person would buy 
        int amount;
        /////////////////////// the tickets prices
        int tprice1 = 0;
        int tprice2 = 0;
        int tprice3 = 0;
        //////////////////////the ticket types
        String ticket1 = null;
        String ticket2 = null;
        String ticket3 = null;

        ////////////////////// the total price
        int price = 0;
        ////////////////////// customers name 
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        ////////////////////// name of seat type
        String seat;


        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("portland2out.txt");
        File file = new File("portlandvip2.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        ////////////////////// getting ticket name and ticket price

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            ticket1 = inputFile.next();
            tprice1 = inputFile.nextInt();
            ticket2 = inputFile.next();
            tprice2 = inputFile.nextInt();
            ticket3 = inputFile.next();
            tprice3 = inputFile.nextInt();
            outputFile.println(ticket1 + " " + "$" + tprice1);
            outputFile.println(ticket2 + " " + "$" + tprice2);
            outputFile.println(ticket3 + " " + "$" + tprice3);

        }

        ////////////////////// getting customer name,number of tickets, type of ticket
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            firstName = inputFile.next();
            lastName = inputFile.next();
            amount = inputFile.nextInt();
            seat = inputFile.next();
            ////////////////////////////////// doing math for final billing.  
            if (seat.equals(ticket1))
                price = tprice1 * amount;
            else if (seat.equals(ticket2))
                price = tprice2 * amount;
            else if (seat.equals(ticket3))
                price = tprice3 * amount;
            ///////////////////////////////// printing in format to file

            outputFile.printf("%-10s%-10s$%,.2f\n", firstName, lastName, price);


        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at BlancovichProject2.main(BlancovichProject2.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at      edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

> I'am not to sure what the problem can be. I've been looking around and it seems that type of error is given when the retrieved information is not exactly what it was looking for. Thanks again in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use

```
ticket1 = inputFile.next();
tprice1 = inputFile.nextInt();
```

on data which look like `Rascal Conway 10 Box` so you are trying to read `Conway` as integer which throws `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: Wouldn't the   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      ticket1=inputFile.next();
      tprice1=inputFile.nextInt();
      ticket2=inputFile.next();
      tprice2=inputFile.nextInt();
      ticket3=inputFile.next();
      tprice3=inputFile.nextInt();                                                     only work on the first 6 variables in the file though then cancel and continue on to the while statement ?

Comment: Not quite. Inside this loop you are reading `String` `int` `String` `int` `String` `int` which handles first 3 lines. But since loop will be executer two times (because of condition `i<2` while `i=0` and then is incremented to `1`) forth line will throw mentioned exception. You can remove this loop and execute code inside it just once. Another problem you will be facing is `f` in `format` method while you are passing integer. In that case you should either explicitly cast value to `float` or `double` or instead of `f` use `d`.

Comment: Alright great I seem to have fixed the errors given by java, and the program runs and makes the file just the file has some formatting issues.  It all prints in the new file but prints all in one line after the first three lines.  Thanks for your help !

Comment: To add line separator in `format` method just add `%n` at end of your format.

Answer (score 0):

It works but you just need to iterate only once or take off the forloop

**change:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        ticket1 = inputFile.next();
        tprice1 = inputFile.nextInt();
        ticket2 = inputFile.next();
        tprice2 = inputFile.nextInt();
        ticket3 = inputFile.next();
        tprice3 = inputFile.nextInt();
        outputFile.println(ticket1 + " " + "$" + tprice1);
        outputFile.println(ticket2 + " " + "$" + tprice2);
        outputFile.println(ticket3 + " " + "$" + tprice3);

    }
```

**to this:**

```
        ticket1 = inputFile.next();
        tprice1 = inputFile.nextInt();
        ticket2 = inputFile.next();
        tprice2 = inputFile.nextInt();
        ticket3 = inputFile.next();
        tprice3 = inputFile.nextInt();
        outputFile.println(ticket1 + " " + "$" + tprice1);
        outputFile.println(ticket2 + " " + "$" + tprice2);
        outputFile.println(ticket3 + " " + "$" + tprice3);
```

Also you have a wrong formating for the printf.To verify the results comment out the

```
 //outputFile.printf("%-10s%-10s$%,.2f\n", firstName, lastName, price);
```

and add this to verify that you have the right output:

```
System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s$%,d\n", firstName, lastName, price);
```

then if they are right... you can output it to your file..

Comment: Thanks just finished fixing the formatting. Got it all the print and save to the file in the correct format.